# SQL Server update rows without nulls ordered by consecutive numbers and nulls

Tags: sql-server, null, grouping, gaps-and-islands

I have query returning few rows. There is column with consecutive numbers and nulls in it.

For example, it has values from 1-10 then 5 nulls, then from 16-30 and then 10 nulls, then from 41-45 and so on.

I need to update that column or create another column to create groupId for consecutive columns.

Meaning as per above example, for rows 1-10, groupID can be 1. Then for 5 nulls nothing and then from 16-30 groupId can be 2. Then for 10 nulls nothing. Then from 41-45 groupId can be 3 and so on.

Please let me know

Comment: Please show us some sample data in tabular form.  Note that there must be some other column which is being used to order, such that the column you describe has 1-10, 5 NULLs, etc.

Comment: This should help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6632/using-row-number-to-find-consecutive-row-count/6633#6633

Comment: why don't you use your programming language to fulfill this?

Answer (score 2):

This was a fun one. Here is the solution with a simple table that contains just integers, but with gaps.

```
create table n(v int)
insert n values (1),(2),(3),(5),(6),(7),(9),(10)

select n.*, g.group_no
from n
join (
select row_number() over (order by low.v) group_no, low.v as low, min(high.v) as high
from n as low
join n as high on high.v>low.v 
    and not exists(select * from n h2 where h2.v=high.v+1)
where not exists(select * from n l2 where l2.v=low.v-1)
group by low.v
) g on g.low<=n.v and g.high>=n.v
```

Result:

```
v   group_no
1   1
2   1
3   1
5   2
6   2
7   2
9   3
10  3
```

Answer (score 1):

Typical island & gap solution

```
select  col, grp = dense_rank() over (order by grp)
from    
(
    select  col, grp = col - dense_rank() over (order by col)
    from    yourtable
) d
```

Comment: Thats much more elegant than mine @Squirrel. Why not just the inner loop slightly adjusted `select  col, grp = col+1 - dense_rank() over (order by col) from tab`

Comment: @TomC what is the reason for `+1` ?

Comment: it was because col-dense_rank() starts at zero.

Comment: it doesn't really matter. The final `grp` is generated from the outer `dense_rank()`. The internal just to assign same value to those belong to the same group

Comment: sorry, that's what I meant by my question. Why do we need the outer loop at all? I'm sure there is a good reason but I can't see it!

Comment: if the `col` is does not starts from 1, then taking `col - dense_ran()` will not give you 0 or 1. So the outer `dense_rank()` is to re-sequence it to starts from 1